# not able to see selected button image in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have app where I am using tab bar controller. For tab bar buttons, I have images of size 30x30 and 60x60.

When I run my app in iOS 6, it shows me selected image, however when I switch to iOS 7, it don't show me selected tab image. Any idea why this is happening?

Below are screenshots for the same.

### iOS 6

[image]

### iOS 7

[image]

---

### Edit 1

On further investigation, I found that this is happening only with first two tab bar. From third to fifth, images are showing fine for iOS7.

Code used is

```
UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home_selected.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search_selected.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ad_with_us_selected.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ad_with_us.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aboutus_selected.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aboutus.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contacts_selected.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contacts.png"];

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];


[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];

[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
[item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage3 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage3];
[item4 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage4 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage4];
```

### Edit 2

Also below is not working in iOS 7.

```
[tabItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:localize(@"fontNameN") size:10.0f], NSFontAttributeName,  [UIColor greenColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

and for `forState:UIControlStateHighlighted` also

### Note

I had created this project in Xcode 4.2 and now for iOS 7, I am opening in Xcode 5. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Have a look at the code that set the selected images (and the text tint color)

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from device \ simulator and cleaning your derived data folder? Before you do that you can easily check if the issue above is cache related by replacing the first image to another image with a different image name.

Comment: @Sha : I have replaced the images... I did reset the simulator and did cleaning also from xcode... but the problem persist...

Comment: @Downvoter : Any problem in this question? what was happening is weird... Its Apples problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Believe it or not

When I remove text that is default in `Title` and `Image` from IB, all is working perfectly now.

[image]

***Apple only knows what was problem***

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
[item0 setSelectedImage:selectedImage0];
```

and so on, because

```
setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:
```

is **deprecated** in iOS 7

Comment: Are you building agains iOS 7 SDK? And have you tried using this? It is deprecated here the doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html